# ¿Es posible mostrar un dropdown diferente dependiendo del dispositivo? con Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Tengo el siguiente código que viene por defecto con el `Bootstrap Auth de Laravel`, lo que requiero es cambiar la dirección del contenido del dropdown dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
        <span class="textnone">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
       <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('home') }}">
              {{ __('Dashboard') }}
          </a>
       </li>
       <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
       <li>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" 
               onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
               {{ __('Logout') }}
           </a>

           <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
               @csrf
           </form>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Cuando el tamaño de la pantalla sea `sm` muestre `<div class="btn-group dropend">` y para el resto `<div class="btn-group dropstart">`